# Ignore newline in rst literal block

Tags: restructuredtext

I have a piece of text that I want to be inside of a rst [literal block](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#literal-blocks), but I also want to break long lines in my document that are more than 70 characters into multiple lines. Is there a way to break up the text in a literal block so that in my editor each line remains below 70 characters in length, but keeps these newlines from the compiled version of the document?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML output, you may use custom CSS, e.g.

```
.. class:: pre-wrap

::

   This is a text with long lines that should wrap in the output if the browser window is nawrrow.
   next line
```

with the CSS rule `.pre-wrap { white-space: pre-wrap; }`.

In Sphinx, use "rst-class" instead of "class" as dirctive name.
In Docutils 0.20, the "pre-wrap rule" is already in the default CSS stylesheet `minimal.css`.